# Jquery Data Table with Rails4 and Turbolinks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables, turbolinks

I'm facing this issue with Data Table plug-in: whenever I press back button of browser, all additional controls like export buttons, search box and pagination are replicated:

[image: Ignore the other buttons. blue buttons are the export one.]

Can anyone suggest why this is happening? I'm using Rails4 with turbolinks.

```
application.js.
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which     will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 //
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
*// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks   
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .*
```

Script to Initialize Data Table in view file document.ready()

```
 var table2 =  $("#example2").DataTable();
 var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table2, {
 buttons: [

   {
            'extend':    'excelHtml5',
            'text':      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o mg-left5" title="Download as Excel"> </i>',
            'titleAttr': 'Excel',
             "exportOptions": {
                        "columns": [0,1,2,3]
                 }
        },
        {
            'extend':    'csvHtml5',
            'text':      '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o mg-left5" title="Download as CSV"> </i>',
            'titleAttr': 'CSV',
             "exportOptions": {
                          "columns": [0,1,2,3]
            }
        }
]
}).container().appendTo($('#table1Buttons'));
```

This is what I have done and not able to figure out what went wrong..

Comment: It might be caused by a conjunction between the Moon and Uranus, they are passing within 2°52' of each other ATM. Or perhaps it is caused by something in your code - but we will never know, this mysterybox seems to be closed forever :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Govind will you update question with application.js code